# Sending Image as base64 is increasing the request size, Is there any other way of sending Image in golang

Tags: json, image, go, image-processing, base64

The images are stored in database as VARBINARY(MAX), I am using golang to retrieve the Image and after converting them into base64 I am making a json payload but it's increasing the request size.

```
    switch err = tx.SelectContext(ctx, &sqlMeetingRoomsInfo, sqlGetMeetingRoomsByFilter, pagenumber, pagesize, customergroupid, bookingtypeid, numberofpeople, startdate, enddate); err {
        case nil:
        case sql.ErrNoRows:
            return lc.JSON(http.StatusOK, resMeetingRoomsInfo)
        default:
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", err)
            return fmt.Errorf("failed %w", err)
        }
    
        for _, v := range sqlMeetingRoomsInfo {
            Data := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(v.Image)
            meetingRoomsInfo := models.ResMeetingRoomsInfo{
                MeetingRoomId:  v.MeetingRoomId,
                Name:           v.Name,
                Layout:         v.Layout,
                LayoutCapacity: v.LayoutCapacity,
                IsEquipment:    v.IsEquipment,
                Image:          Data,
            }
            resMeetingRoomsInfo = append(resMeetingRoomsInfo, meetingRoomsInfo)
        }
```

After trying this someone suggested to directly send the image without converting them to base64 but I don't know how it will be loaded into json payload.

Comment: JSON doesn't support sending binary data, so if you need to send the request in JSON format you don't really have another choice. You could use some other encoding and reduce the size a bit more.

Comment: I support @super. In json return your custom URL to get image, then create another handler on that URL that returns the image as binary with proper `Content-Type`

Comment: JSON is for text, not for binary data. If you need to efficiently transport binary data use a more efficient binary-friendly encoding like protobuf.

Comment: Your question seems to _imply_ the context of a data exchange happening "on the web" using HTTP protocol. If I'm correct, there's no restriction on sending binary data in the HTTP protocol itself. Novice web devs seem to be fixated on JSON because that's what they get taught—while skipping all the lower-level details about how the web works. Hence if you control the definition of the application-level protocol which the data exchange you're describing is a part of, you can make this exchange more efficient.

Comment: Images shouldn't be in the database anyway; they're opaque, non relational data that would be better stored in an object store with a reference in the database